# How to group by single field and return more values together

Tags: group-by, druid

I'm starting to use `apache druid` but having some difficult to run **native queries** (and some SQL too).

1- Is it possible to `groupBy` a single column while also returning more channels?

2- How could I `groupBy` a single column, while returning different grouped itens on same query/row ?

Query I'm trying to use:

```
{
  "queryType": "groupBy",
  "dataSource": "my-data-source",
  "granularity": "all",
  "intervals": ["2022-06-27T03:00:00.000Z/2022-06-28T03:00:00.000Z"],
  "context:": { "timeout: 30000 },
  "dimensions": ["userId"],
  "filter": {
    "type": "and",
    "fields": [
      {
        "type": "or",
        "fields": [{...}]
      }
    ]
  },
  "aggregations": [
    {
      "type": "count",
      "name": "count"
    }
  ]
}
```

Tried to add a [filtered](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/querying/aggregations.html#filtered-aggregator) type inside `aggregations:[]` but 0 changes happened.

```
"aggregations": [
  {
    "type: "count",
     "name": "count"
  },
  {
    "type": "filtered",
    "filter": {
      "type": "selector",
      "dimension": "block_id",
      "value": "block1"
    },
    "aggregator": {
      "type": "count",
      "name": "block1",
      "fieldName": "block_id" 
     }
  }
]
```

[Grouping Aggregator](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/querying/aggregations.html#grouping-aggregator) also didn't work.

```
    "aggregations": [
      {
        "type": "count",
        "name": "count"
      },
      {
        "type": "grouping",
        "name": "groupedData",
        "groupings": ["block_id"]
      }
    ],
```

Below is the image illustrating the results I'm trying to achieve.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure yet how to get the results in the format you want, but as a start, something like this might be a step:

```
{
  "queryType": "groupBy",
  "dataSource": {
    "type": "table",
    "name": "dataTest"
  },
  "intervals": {
    "type": "intervals",
    "intervals": [
      "-146136543-09-08T08:23:32.096Z/146140482-04-24T15:36:27.903Z"
    ]
  },
  "filter": null,
  "granularity": {
    "type": "all"
  },
  "dimensions": [
    {
      "type": "default",
      "dimension": "d2_ts2",
      "outputType": "STRING"
    },
    {
      "type": "default",
      "dimension": "d3_email",
      "outputType": "STRING"
    }
  ],
  "aggregations": [
    {
      "type": "count",
      "name": "myCount",
    }
  ],
  "descending": false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious, what is the use case?

Using a SQL query you can do it this way:

```
SELECT UserID, 
sum(1) FILTER (WHERE BlockId = 'block1') as Block1,
sum(1) FILTER (WHERE BlockId = 'block2') as Block2,
sum(1) FILTER (WHERE BlockId = 'block3') as Block3

FROM inline_data
GROUP BY 1
```

The Native Query for this (from the explain) is:

```
{
  "queryType": "topN",
  "dataSource": {
    "type": "table",
    "name": "inline_data"
  },
  "virtualColumns": [
    {
      "type": "expression",
      "name": "v0",
      "expression": "1",
      "outputType": "LONG"
    }
  ],
  "dimension": {
    "type": "default",
    "dimension": "UserID",
    "outputName": "d0",
    "outputType": "STRING"
  },
  "metric": {
    "type": "dimension",
    "previousStop": null,
    "ordering": {
      "type": "lexicographic"
    }
  },
  "threshold": 101,
  "intervals": {
    "type": "intervals",
    "intervals": [
      "-146136543-09-08T08:23:32.096Z/146140482-04-24T15:36:27.903Z"
    ]
  },
  "filter": null,
  "granularity": {
    "type": "all"
  },
  "aggregations": [
    {
      "type": "filtered",
      "aggregator": {
        "type": "longSum",
        "name": "a0",
        "fieldName": "v0",
        "expression": null
      },
      "filter": {
        "type": "selector",
        "dimension": "BlockId",
        "value": "block1",
        "extractionFn": null
      },
      "name": "a0"
    },
    {
      "type": "filtered",
      "aggregator": {
        "type": "longSum",
        "name": "a1",
        "fieldName": "v0",
        "expression": null
      },
      "filter": {
        "type": "selector",
        "dimension": "BlockId",
        "value": "block2",
        "extractionFn": null
      },
      "name": "a1"
    },
    {
      "type": "filtered",
      "aggregator": {
        "type": "longSum",
        "name": "a2",
        "fieldName": "v0",
        "expression": null
      },
      "filter": {
        "type": "selector",
        "dimension": "BlockId",
        "value": "block3",
        "extractionFn": null
      },
      "name": "a2"
    }
  ],
  "postAggregations": [],
  "context": {
    "populateCache": false,
    "sqlOuterLimit": 101,
    "sqlQueryId": "bb92e899-c127-49b0-be1b-d4b38909d166",
    "useApproximateCountDistinct": false,
    "useApproximateTopN": false,
    "useCache": false,
    "useNativeQueryExplain": true
  },
  "descending": false
}
```